How can change the icon shape from Square to Circle on HyperOS?
I disabled the MiUI optimization & the icon shape was made squares from circle which was before. How to revert it to circle ? I don't want to re-enable MiUI optimization. I prefer solutions if it exists some settings about that or via ADB Command.
I tried to find some similar settings in developer mode or in settings but didn't find something. Thanks in advance !
